# How to reboot a remote machine automatically periodically(weekly)?

Tags: ansible

Is there any ansible module to reboot a remote machine automatically periodically(weekly)?

As of now i am running a playbook using reboot module by crontab.

Comment: May i know why was that -ve vote please?

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't. And there is no time-trigger in the module [reboot](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html).

If you need Ansible for this "Running a playbook using reboot module by crontab" is the best practice to "Reboot a remote machine automatically periodically(weekly)".

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a crontab entry with ansible which is doing the reboot?

```
- name: Add Reboot Entry to Cron
  cron:
    name: "Reboot weekly"
    job:  "/usr/bin/reboot"
    minute:  "0"
    hour:    "4"
    weekday: "2"
```

Comment: Above mentioned playbook is gonna add a entry into crontab of the remote machine is it?

Comment: Yes. If you use `localhost` then the entry would be added to the machine where ansible is executed.